# Derivative of matrix vector product with respect to $3$D rotation matrices.

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, rotations

I have a class of probability densities that are indexed by $3$D rotation matrices. I am working on an estimation problem, so I want to find the fisher information, but that requires taking derivatives of the densities with respect to the rotation matrices.

Let $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ be a $3$D rotation matrix, and let $f(Q) = Y_1(Q)\cdots Y_n(Q) x \in R^{n}$ be a function that maps a rotation matrix to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $Y_i(Q)$ are matrices that are a function of $Q$ and $x$ a constant vector,  what is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $Q$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial Q}$$.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't going to be pleasant. Since $f$ is a vector, this derivative would be a rank $3$ tensor. When you have complicated functions, going through the derivatives systematically with chain rule is not always the best approach. There might be away to avoid higher order tensors if this is part of a chain rule involving the derivative of a scalar.

Comment: You write $f(Q) = \dots$, but there is no $Q$ on the RHS. Are the $Y_1,\dots, Y_n$ somehow related to $Q$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clearer. $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ are matrices that are a function of $Q$. I replaced $Y_i$ with $Y_i(Q)$ in my question for clarity. Also, $x$ is a constant vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have a function $F:V\to W$ between two normed vector spaces (say over the field $\Bbb{R}$), then given a point $\alpha\in V$, the derivative $DF_{\alpha}$ (also commonly denoted as $dF_{\alpha}$) is by definition a linear transformation $V\to W$; i.e $DF_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, so you can evaluate on a vector $v\in V$ to get $DF_{\alpha}(v) \in W$.

Now with this introduction out of the way, all the familiar rules of differential calculus (eg chain rule, product rule etc) all work as usual. In your case, $V= M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ and $W = \Bbb{R}^n$, and so the product rule (differentiate each function successively and leave all others untouched, in the same order) implies that
\begin{align}
Df &=
\sum_{k=1}^n Y_1\cdots Y_{k-1} \cdot(DY_k)\cdot Y_{k+1} \cdots Y_n \cdot x.
\end{align}
This is a slightly condensed notation, where we do not say where things are being evaluated. If we want to be slightly more explicit, then for all $Q,\xi\in V$ we have
\begin{align}
Df_Q[\xi] &= \sum_{k=1}^n Y_1(Q)\cdots Y_{k-1} \cdot(DY_k)_Q[\xi]\cdot Y_{k+1}(Q) \cdots Y_n(Q) \cdot x \quad \in W
\end{align}
Without further information, this is about as simple as it can get.

This is a huge amount of information, because $Df_Q\in \mathcal{L}(V,W) = \mathcal{L}(M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R}), \Bbb{R}^n)$ is a linear transformation between spaces of large dimension, and if you were to try to represent this linear transformation as a matrix, it would be very ugly very quickly (any matrix representation of this linear map will be of size $n\times n^2$), so unless you really need to write in matrix form, I would avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\A{{\cal A}}\def\B{{\cal B}}\def\C{{\cal C}}
$Introducing the partial product notation
$$\eqalign{
P_{i,j}
 &= Y_{i}\;Y_{i+1}\cdots Y_{j}\qquad&(i\le j) \\
 &= I &(i>j) \\
}$$
the differential and gradient of the function can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
df &= \sum_{k=1}^n P_{1,k-1}\:dY_k\:(P_{k+1,n}\:x) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n \Big[P_{1,k-1}\star(P_{k+1,n}\:x)\Big]:dY_k \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n\Big[P_{1,k-1}\star(P_{k+1,n}\:x)\Big]:\gradLR{Y_k}{Q}:dQ \\
\grad{f}{Q}
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n\Big[P_{1,k-1}\star(P_{k+1,n}\:x)\Big]:\gradLR{Y_k}{Q} \\
}$$
where $(\star)$ denotes the tensor product
and $(:)$ is the double-dot product
$$\eqalign{
&\B = A\star X \qiq \B_{ijkl} = A_{ij} X_{kl} \\
&G=M:\B \qiq G_{kl} = \sum_{i}\sum_{j} M_{ij}\B_{ijkl} \\
}$$

Since you didn't specified the $Y_k$ functions, I will assume that you already know how to calculate those tensor-valued gradients $\gradLR{Y_k}{Q}$